# Why is setTimeout animation in javascript not working the way that i want it to?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript . I tried to do learn a bit of animation techniques using setTimeout.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var animate;
    var moveImg=null;
    function init(){
        moveImg=document.getElementById("ashu");
        moveImg.style.position="relative";
        moveImg.style.left="1px"; 
        return moveImg;
    }
    function start(){
        while(moveImg.style.left!=null){
            moveImg.style.left=parseInt(moveImg.style.left)+10+'px'
                if(moveImg.style.left<"100px"){
                    animate=setTimeout(start,200);
                }else{
                    clearTimeout(animate);
                    moveImg.style.left="0px";
                }
        }
    function stop(){
        clearTimeout(animate);
        moveImg.style.left="0px";
    }
    window.onload=init;
    </script>
```

The html file:

```
<body>
    <img src="ashu.jpg" id="ashu" width="500px" height="250">
    <br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="start()" value="Start">
    <br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="stop()" value="Stop">
</body>
```

When i click the start button . Nothing happens.

Comment: `moveImg.style.left<"100px"` is not your intended comparison.. this way you are comparing strings not numbers

Comment: How can i be so stupid. Probably its just the night ,that's why. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The `while` loop blocks the event loop. Therefore setTimeout never gets a chance to execute the function you passed to it. Also, even if you manage to execute a function, the `while` loop blocks browser DOM update. Therefore you'll never be able to see the animation in action.

Comment: probably then not best time to learn.. go get some sleep.. or working in night shift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `while` loop and use proper comparison with `100` instead of `100px`:

```js
var animate;
var moveImg = null;

function init() {
    moveImg = document.getElementById("ashu");
    moveImg.style.position = "relative";
    moveImg.style.left = "1px";
    return moveImg;
}

function start() {
    moveImg.style.left = parseInt(moveImg.style.left) + 10 + 'px'
    if (parseInt(moveImg.style.left) < 100) {
        animate = setTimeout(start, 200);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(animate);
        moveImg.style.left = "0px";
    }
}

function stop() {
    clearTimeout(animate);
    moveImg.style.left = "0px";
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" id="ashu">
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="start()" value="Start">
<br/>
```

You might also want to decrease timeout and left shift for smoother animation:

```
moveImg.style.left = parseInt(moveImg.style.left) + 5 + 'px'
if (parseInt(moveImg.style.left) < 100) {
    animate = setTimeout(start, 30);
}
```

or better to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) function:

```
function start() {
    moveImg.style.left = parseInt(moveImg.style.left) + 2 + 'px'
    if (parseInt(moveImg.style.left) < 100) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(start);
    } else {
        moveImg.style.left = "0px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                moveImg.style.left=(parseInt(moveImg.style.left)+10)+'px'
                if((parseInt(moveImg.style.left)+10) < 100){
                    animate=setTimeout(start,200);
                }else{
                    clearTimeout(animate);
                    moveImg.style.left="0px";
                }
```